# Identify this Alps potentiometer

Tags: identification, components, potentiometer

I'm trying to replace a broken potentiometer on a Native Instruments Traktor Kontrol S2.

My guess is that it is from the [Alps RK11K](https://tech.alpsalpine.com/prod/e/pdf/potentiometer/rotarypotentiometers/rk11k11/rk11k11.pdf) series.

From what I can see:

**Part number**: 103B 305C - I haven't been able to line this up exactly with any part but I think the "103B" represents 1B taper and the total resistance (I tested the resistance with a multi-meter).

**Total Resistance**: 10 kΩ

**Length of the shaft**: 14-15 mm (from the top of the bushing)

**Pinout**: 4 pins

I've contacted Alps but haven't got a response, any help on not only identifying the part but understanding any steps I could take to do it myself would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Is the tap terminal used?

Comment: Looks like the one  with bushing RK11K114. R-S electronics may have some in UK otherwise , mouser.com, or Digikey

Comment: @SpehroPefhany, looking at the traces, I'm fairly sure only 2 terminals are used.

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75  rk11k114 seems to still represent a lot of different possibilities

Comment: The suffix defines the orientation and thread mount

Answer (score 1):

I've realised that by filtering on also needing a centre detent it's definitly the RK11K114001Z.

Unfortunately, it's hard to buy just 1 for a reasonable price.